# JavaFX, Problem with positiong radio buttons over Stack Pane

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I've doing some application for checking time on the world. I want use Radio Buttons over the map of the world for representing Cities. But I have a problem with positioning this buttons over my World Map. There is my fxml file. How can i move this button for the amount px I want. There is my FXML file. I set stack Pane background image in css file. In main.java I only set app to not be resizable.

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<BorderPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            stylesheets="@styles.css">
    <top>
        <TilePane alignment="center" hgap="5" vgap="5">
        <padding><Insets top="5" bottom="10" left="5" right="5"/></padding>
            <Button text="Europa" />

            <Button text="Afryka" />

            <Button text="Azja" id="button_three" />

            <Button text="Australia" />

            <Button text="Ameryka Północna" />

            <Button text="Ameryka Południowa"/>

        </TilePane>

    </top>

    <center>
        <StackPane id="Europa" prefWidth="700" prefHeight="650" >
            <RadioButton text="Londyn" />

            <RadioButton text="Warszawa"/>
        </StackPane>
    </center>

    <bottom>

    </bottom>

    <right>
        <VBox alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
            <Label text="Your City :"/>
            <Label text="Time in your City :"/>
        </VBox>
    </right>
</BorderPane>
```

Also when I tried positioning like that it works but space over the button and on the left also activates button so I guess it is not a proper way

```
 <center>
        <StackPane id="Europa" alignment="TOP_LEFT" prefWidth="700" prefHeight="650"  >
            <RadioButton text="Londyn" >
            <padding><Insets top="50" left="50"/></padding>
            </RadioButton>
            <RadioButton text="Warszawa"/>
        </StackPane>
    </center>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer. In the Stack Pane to move my buttons i have to operate X an Y axis the proper way to do that in FXML file  is for example:

```
<RadioButton text="Warszawa" translateX="500" translateY="100"/>
```